# How to run scalatest in parallel with maven surefire plugin?

Tags: maven, scalatest, maven-surefire-plugin, parallel-testing

I'm working on a scala project which use Maven to build and `maven-surefire-plugin` to run the tests written in scalatest.

The tests are like:

```
import org.scalatest.ParallelTestExecution

@RunWith(classOf[org.scalatest.junit.JUnitRunner])
class MyTest extends FunSuite with ParallelTestExecution {
   // some tests
}
```

From some questions, I know that if we give a `-P` argument to scalatest, it will run the tests in parallel.

But I'm not sure how to configure it with `maven-surefire-plugin`, I tried to add  `-P`, but which causes the JVM unable to start:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <argLine>-P</argLine>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Is there any way to do it? If we can't do it with maven surefire plugin, is it possible to configure it just in tests?

Answer (score 0):

If all of your tests are written with scalatest, you should be using the scalatest maven plugin rather than surefire. There's

doc:
http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_the_scalatest_maven_plugin

source:
https://github.com/scalatest/scalatest-maven-plugin

Comment: Note that if you do use the scalatest maven plugin then you can't use java testing in your code. If you have mixed java/scala project then using surefire and decorating with @RunWith is the only way I know of

Comment: @AssafMendelson To be more clear, you still can test Java but using scalatest.

Comment: This found all of the tests in my project that extend from PlaySpec (from ScalaTestPlus-Play, and that extends from something in scalatest), but not Specification (from Play-Spec2).